# Are there any extra considerations to gluing pressure treated lumber?

Tags: lumber, glue, pressure-treated

I am in the process of designing a floating raft, which will be built out of pressure treated lumber. There are various elements I would like create from gluing together some smaller boards rather than purchasing more expensive, larger stock.

Does gluing the pressure treated lumber entail extra considerations, or should I just approach it like gluing regular lumber? Does this projects future being perpetually wet also warrant extra scrutiny?

Answer (score 3):

The extended contact with water is going to by far be the more important consideration.  The only glue I know of that handles being perpetually wet is epoxy.  There are entire product lines of epoxy especially made for boat building.  Check out http://www.westsystem.com for one.

Answer (score 3):

First. Gluing pressure treated lumber. Once it has dried again it should glue like regular wood.  It won't work at all if the lumber is still wet from the pressure treatment.

Second issue, to make this work with glue you will have to get glue that does not react with water.  Normal 'wood' glue, the yellow stuff won't last long at all.

Is there any particular reason you are not using some other form of attachment?  Nails, screws, etc?